# WCF - When object to transfer has a list of more than 127 objects

Tags: wcf, configuration, code-first

i use WCF with Code First (VS 2012, .NET 4.0, WCF 5). Everything works fine unless i want to transfer an large object. It contains a list of many other objects. Every object has only small content. If this list is longer than 127 objects, i get an exception:

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by
>   a contract mismatch,  a premature session shutdown or an internal
>   server error.

I found that out by reducing column count in database (try and error).

I use the following configuration on the client:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_****_Service" closeTimeout="00:00:10"
          openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/****" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="****" contract="****"
        name="NetTcpBinding_****Service">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="****" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The server configuration looks as follows:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_****_Service" closeTimeout="00:00:10"
          openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
          transferMode="Buffered" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxConnections="0" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="100000" maxStringContentLength="100000"
            maxArrayLength="100000" maxBytesPerRead="100000" maxNameTableCharCount="100000" />
          <reliableSession enabled="false" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="****">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_****_Service"
          contract="****" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8000/****" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Please excuse the masking of some names. I need to avoid that one can draw inferences from these names about the project. :D

Answer (score 0):

At first, set this property on server side (just for dev)

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
```

that specifies whether to include managed exception information in the detail of SOAP faults returned to the client for debugging purposes.

It's sure there is something wrong when processing your request but you don't have any debug information. That's why you have to set this property. You can also turn on WCF Tracing but it's a bit more difficult.

WCF have many quotas : A quota is a hard limit that prevents the use of additional resources once the quota value is exceeded.

There are especially two quotas you need to be aware when sending large data : maxReceivedMessageSize and MaxItemsInObjectGraph.